# The Deal with Stunt Dice in Fiasco

Tags: fiasco

I played my first game of Fiasco earlier this week, and had a blast. We used the ["Camp Death" playset](http://www.bullypulpitgames.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camp_Death) and I acted as a facilitor. Camp Death uses the "stunt dice" rule. Basically, whenever one of the those dice is chosen, someone (most likely an NPC) dies. However, I found that having four stunt dice reduced rolls during the Tilt and the Aftermath, as the stunt dice were not counted either time.

Did we do something incorrectly? It seems like there was even less chance of getting a 'good' result on the Aftermath tables with the stunt dice present. Which isn't a huge deal, but it seemed odd.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Playset author here. Glad you had fun with it!

You did everything right. My decision to omit the stunt dice from the aftermath was intentional, precisely to increase the chance that everyone would have lower/worse Aftermath totals. The playset is modeled after slasher flicks, after all; rarely does anyone escape unscathed.

And regarding the Tilt, I should have specified more clearly in the playset: You DO use the stunt dice remaining in the pool.

This goes for stunt dice "Camp Death," but not necessarily any other playset. There aren't really any set "best practices" for how to implement them. The general idea is to swap in a few different-colored dice during the Setup that affect scene resolution in a specific way, but I figure out how they interact with the other moving parts of the game on a playset-by-playset basis.

Answer (score 3):

It affects the results, but not too much.

- You're less likely to have the highest White or Black total during the Tilt if you have stunt dice. The playset isn't specific, but I assume you don't roll them for the Tilt.
- Everyone is going to tend to a worse result in the Aftermath, which seems fitting for the genre.